# Simplest way to implement collision in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

what is the simplest way to implement collision?
Given all particles have same speed and same mass but different directions. And even after collision their speed and mass remains the same but direction that is heading changes.
Would it be possible to implement collision btw more than two particles?

Comment: Understand wanting the particles not to change mass... but why wouldn't they change speed?

Comment: Looks like the question will be closed as too broad. You might be able to stop it by adding more detail about what you're trying to do — especially if you can illustrate it with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [example implementation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/GasLabSingleCollision) with the following rules:

> Particles behave according to the following rules:
>
> 1. A particle moves in a straight line without changing its speed, unless it collides with another particle or bounces off the wall. The
>    particles are aimed to hit each other at the origin.
> 2. Two particles "collide" if they find themselves on the same patch (the world is composed of a grid of small squares called patches).
> 3. A random axis is chosen, as if they are two balls that hit each other and this axis is the line connecting their centers.
> 4. They exchange momentum and energy along that axis, according to the conservation of momentum and energy. This calculation is done in the
>    center of mass system.
> 5. Each turtle is assigned its new velocity, energy, and heading.
> 6. If a turtle finds itself on or very close to a wall of the container, it "bounces" -- that is, reflects its direction and keeps
>    its same speed.

If you have a specific question on any part of this logic feel free to comment.